# $\omega$ covers and Lindelöf property

Tags: general-topology

As similarly described in a question [represented here before:](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/507599/8348)

Let $\langle \mathcal{U}_n: n \in \mathbb{N} \rangle$ be a sequence of $\omega$-covers of $X$, and suppose that $X$ is [Lindelöf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindel%C3%B6f_space). Can we always find a sequence $\langle F_n: n \in \mathbb{N} \rangle$ with each $F_n \in \mathcal{U}_n$ such that $\cup F_n$ is an open cover of $X$?

Thank you!

Note: The property that $X$ is **Lindelöf** was **not** an assumption in the referred question.

Comment: But, as far as I know, $\mathbb R$ is not lindeloff.. am I wrong about that?

Comment: Of course $\mathbb{R}$ is Lindelöf: every second-countable space is Lindelöf.

Comment: But, if we cover each open interval $(n,n+1)$, by open segments of length $\frac{1}{2^{2^n}}$, isn't the union of any countable set of intervals going to be with finite length? what am I missing here

Comment: @Shir: That won't cover $\mathbb{R}$.  In particular, no integers will be contained in any of these sets.

Comment: @Shir: Let's put it another way: for each $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ the closed interval $[n,n+1]$ is compact, and $\mathbb{R} = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} [n,n+1]$.  Given any open cover $\mathcal{U}$ of $\mathbb{R}$ fix for each $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ a _finite_ $\mathcal{V}_n \subseteq \mathcal{U}$ which covers $[n,n+1]$.  Then $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \mathcal{V}_n$ is a countable subcover of $\mathcal{U}$.

Comment: Yes of course... sorry, you are absolutly right....